# How to Convert additional Keyboard into PC Joystick / gamepad

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, gaming, game-controller

I am playing an EA sports Cricket game. 2 Player is identified/enabled in game only if I plug in a Joystick into my laptop.

Now my joystick is not working, I want to use my additional keyboard as a Joystick so that the game can identify it as a 2nd player automatically.

> My system info: Windows 7 64bit

I am using EA sports cricket 2007. The game detects the second player only if a joystick is inserted. I want to play the second player with my second keyboard. I have an additional keyboard. My joystick was working in windows7 x32 bit but when i changed it to x64 bit, it says device(joystick) not recoginized. I tried with multiple drivers from the internet, its not working.

So now i need, either use second keyboard as a joystick or how to use my joystick in 64bit.

Comment: Which version of EA Sports Cricket are you playing? Do you simply want to enable the second player, or should the second player use the second keyboard for control?

Comment: i am using, ea sports cricket 2007. The game deducts the second player only if joystick is inserted. I want to play the second player in keyboard itself. I have additional keyboard. My joystick was working in windows7 x32 bit but when i changed it to x64 bit, it says device(joystick) not recoginized. I tried with multiple driver softwares from internet, its not working. So now i need, either use second keyboard as joystick or how to use joystick for 64bit

Comment: I would suggest you to install the games in compatibility mode and check if it works.

Comment: @anurag shetti : the game is portable and the game is working fine. The problem is joystick is not working in x64 bit. And i want to use my keyboard as secondary player.

Answer (score 1):

This software sits between the keyboards and the Windows stack, allowing to distinguish keyboards and convert all or some of them into "Xbox Controllers":
https://github.com/djlastnight/KeyboardSplitterXbox

With it, you can keep your first keyboard and mouse, and convert a second keyboard into a virtual Xbox Controller.

I tested it with Windows 10 and the two-player mode of "Lego Star Wars - Skywalker Saga", which, contrary to former Lego Star Wars games, insists on a gamepad / controller for two-player mode.

Comment: Welcome. Just to let you know, you are required to declare any affiliation with it.

Comment: I have no affiliation with the KeyboardSplitterXbox project other than I found it through a Google search after not having any success with the other answers. Did anything made you think specifically that I am affiliated with it? I thought from the last paragraph it would be clear that I'm just a user, sorry if that was not enough.

Comment: It was not an accusation.  It's just that, as per guidelines, you are required to declare your affiliations to products and links.  Spammers, will always pretend they are a user, so that is not normally enough :-)

Comment: I did not link to any commercial product, but to an open-source repository that helped me. No money involved. I can only hope it will help others in the same situation. I did not take it as an accusation, but I'm puzzled - StackOverflow, Superuser etc. are full of links to open-source projects, and usually people are not asked in a comment to declare their affiliations. Not sure why you asked me. Spammers and AI accounts are a real problem, of course. If they are "good", they will also respond to such comments.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... I think [RBjoy](http://www.rbsoft.de/html/rb-joy.html) is what you're looking for.

> - Emulate keystrokes and mouse clicks with the joystick or gamepad
> - Simulating keypresses or mouse-events with the joystick or gamepad

I don't know if it's still compatible with the new Windows OS; by the way you can always try!

Comment: hi, will rbjoy convert the keyboard input to joystick input ? And the page link is in some other language. I need it in english.

Comment: for Keyboard to Joypad there is [JoytoKey](http://www.electracode.com/4/joy2key/JoyToKey%20English%20Version.htm), RBjoy does both

Comment: It converts joystick input into keyboard input; I dont have joystick , i need keyboard to be converted as joystick input. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [VJoy](http://headsoft.com.au/index.php?category=vjoy) and it works unless you want an Xbox 360 controller layout. Anyway, I don't quite think there's an official method on Windows to actually split the input of the two keyboards.